# Distribute Numbers So That Each Bucket Is Relatively Even

Tags: algorithm, math, distribution

I'm working on some aspect of my game involving a depot. I'm trying to write a Resupply(stock) method so that it will resupply this depot object so that each resource in the depot is as evenly distributed as possible.

The depot has a finite maximum capacity (meaning it should not be possible to overstock a depot beyond its capacity). The depot defines a finite set of resources, that have a quantity (the number of items), as well as a multiplier (ie. You can have 4 units of Wood, but because of their large size they have a multiplier of 2, making the 4 units take up 8 units of space overall)

Take this example of a depot:

Depot A has a maximum capacity of 100, and it's current capacity is 50 (so 50% full)

There are 4 types of resources in this depot

```
A: 4 Units, Multiplier of 4     - (4 * 4) / 100 = 16%
B: 3 Units, Multiplier of 3     - (3 * 3) / 100 = 9%
C: 15 Units, Multiplier of 1    - (15 * 1) / 100 = 15%
D: 5 Units, Multiplier of 2     - (5 * 2) / 100 = 10%
```

Now say I wish to restock this depot by giving it 25 new units (these units are magical and for gameplay purposes can allocate themselves to any resource bucket).

How would I best distribute these 25 points so that the allocation of resources A,B,C,D are more or less equal to each other?

Lets say for a first pass we add 2 Units to B, and 3 Units to D:

```
B: Add 2 Units - (3 + 2) * 3    - 15 / 100 = 0.15
D: Add 3 Units - (5 + 3) * 2    - 16 / 100 = 0.16
```

After giving 5 units away, A,B,C,D share almost the same amount of storage in the depot. (16%,15%,15%,16%)

How would I achieve this:

- With n number of resources defined in a depot?
- With any m maximum capacity?
- With any n current capacity?
- Never adding more units than the Maximum Capacity? (extra units are discarded)

Comment: n is redefined in the problem, number of resources and current capacity

Comment: For exact solutions, you can use Mixed-integer programming. This problem feels NP-hard in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a simple greedy algorithm:

- ignore any resource that cannot be increased without exceeding the
  depot capacity
- of the remaining resources find the one taking the least amount of
  space

  - if there's a tie, choose the resource with the smaller multiplier
- add 1 unit to that resource type
- repeat until all new units are used or none of the resources can be
  increased

Here's how the algorithm proceeds with the given example:

```
      -  B  D  D  B  D  C  B  C  D  A  C  C  D  B  C  C  D  A  C  B  C  D  C  C  D
4 A  16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24
3 B   9 12 12 12 15 15 15 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 21 21 21 21 21 21 24 24 24 24 24 24
1 C  15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 17 17 17 18 19 19 19 20 21 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 25 25
2 D  10 10 12 14 14 16 16 16 16 18 18 18 18 20 20 20 20 22 22 22 22 22 24 24 24 26
```

Comment: This looks simple enough to implement, the only part I dislike is having to search/sort on each iteration as that can get computationally expensive. Perhaps there are ways of reducing the amount of searching/sorting required?

Comment: @Igneous01 That's a valid point. In order to assess the performance impacts, you need to consider the actual worst case numbers: maximum number of resources in a single depot, maximum number of units added, how fast are depots updated. For this example with 4 resources and 25 new units, the running time of the algorithm was 1.7usec. That's only 0.02% of the frame time (assuming 120 frames per second). So there's no point in optimizing it unless you have a very large number of resource types, or are adding a very large number of units, or are updating many depots per frame.